# how to extract mongo log between two dates using bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash, ubuntu

i traing to extract access log and between two dates from mongo log file . but i can  only extract access log not between two dates .sample of mongo log date format

```
2020-10-01T21:55:56.402+0530 I  ACCESS   [conn2] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { getLog: "startupWarnings", ....}
2020-10-01T21:55:56.402+0530 I  ACCESS   [conn2] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { getFreeMonitoringStatus: 1.0, ......}
```

```
#!/bin/bash


# Current Time
TIME=`/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y-%T`

#What to Backup(mongo).
BACKUP_FILE="/home/ubuntu/mongotest.log"

#Where to Backup Store.
DEST="/home/ubuntu/filterlogs"

#log file of backup file
NEW_FILE=$DEST/$TIME.log


#Create backup dir
/bin/mkdir -p $DEST

grep -w "ACCESS"   "$BACKUP_FILE" >> "$NEW_FILE"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $BACKUP_FILE to $TIME.log"
```

Comment: Check the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool as [recommended by MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/). Something like `jq '. | select(.t["$date"] >= "2020-04-15T00:00:00.000" and .t["$date"] <= "2020-04-15T23:59:59.999") and .c=="ACCESS"' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit getting error parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1 ,column 14

Comment: Which Mongo version do you use? Older than 4.4. Before 4.4 the log format was plain text instead of JSON. `jq` works only with JSON. Otherwise you have to consult `grep`, `awk`, etc.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes i am using older version 4.0 something .can you provide solution to  filter date log using awk till now i successfully filter 'ACCESS' logs form mongo log file
awk '/ACCESS/ {print}' mongodtest.log > test.log

Comment: First approach could be another grep on `"^2020-10-01T21:" `

Comment: @Siddhesh Kirve - How do you want to specify the _two dates_?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit in your example, I think the "and .c=="ACCESS" needs to be inside the select parenthesis.  Like this: 
`jq '. | select(.t["$date"] >= "2020-04-15T00:00:00.000" and .t["$date"] <= "2020-04-15T23:59:59.999" and .c=="ACCESS") ' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`